# How do I access the values of my results from a view

Tags: views, 8

I have a preprocess function that I would like to run against a view, but I can not seem to be able to access the actual results. I have a custom entity called entity1 with two fields, field1 and field2. This function runs, but the value of $value is never set

```
function template_preprocess_views_view_hook(&$variables) {
  // View options set by user.

  foreach ($variables['view']->result as $id => $result) {
    //Things I've tried:
    $value1 = $result->field_field_field1;
    $value2 = $result->field_field_field1[0]['raw']['value'];
    $value3 = $result->entity1_field_field1;
    $value4 = $result->field1;
    //and many other things
  }
}
```

The foreach loop does in fact cycle through for the correct number of results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the method getValue() from each `field` to get the field data from `row`:

```
$view = $variables['view'];
$values = [];
foreach ($view->result as $row_id => $row) {
  foreach ($view->field as $field_id => $field ) {
    $values[$row_id][$field_id] = $field->getValue($row);
  }
}
```

If you want the rendered field use `$field->render($row)`

Comment: I found that $value = $result[$id]->_entity->field1->value, but your code looks better.

Comment: That's the field value from the entity, not from the view result.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Luckily in my case they are the same, but I can imagine in many cases they would not.